# Handling a keyerror with a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I fix a `KeyError` in a python dictionary?

I was asked to create a dictionary and create a function `number_dictionary(text, n)`. I'm able to return `True` or `False` if the `text` matches the `n`, but there's a `KeyError` when I put something that's not in the dictionary when it is supposed to return `False`.

I've put the two conditions together (when it does not match and not in the dictionary), but then it returns everything as `False`.

```
def number_dictionary(text,n):
    numbers={'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4'}
    if n != numbers[text] or n or text not in numbers:
        return(False)
    else:
        return(True)
```

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) particularly [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three options:

- [Catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

  ```
  try:
       foo = somedictionary[bar]
  except KeyError:
       return False
  ```
- Use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return a default value instead, that default value defaults to `None`:

  ```
  foo = somedictionary.get(bar)  # return None if bar is not a key
  ```
- Test for the key seperately:

  ```
  if bar not in somedictionary:
      return False
  ```

In your case you tested for the key *after* trying to access it. You could swap the test (dropping the `or n`):

```
def number_dictionary(text, n):
    numbers={'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4'}
    return text not in numbers or n != numbers[text]
```

Or just use `dict.get()`, the default `None` will never match a string `n`:

```
def number_dictionary(text, n):
    numbers = {'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4'}
    return numbers.get(text) == n
```

Both the `not in` and `==` comparison tests already produce either `True` or `False`, so there is no need to use `if` and separate `return` statements.

Comment: I would put ```.get()``` the first and ```try .. except``` the last.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: Why would that be? Both are valid options, neither has a clear advantage in general. It depends on how frequently the key is missing which option is faster, for example. In other words: it depends on the specific code and the typical frequencies of the keys being probed.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It fixed the problem :) there's actually a test for a hidden input do you know what that is?

Comment: @ameliagunawan: no idea what that might be; perhaps you could ask that in a new question? Don't forget to include a [mcve]!